# Hello everbody !!!I have created yandex map but I couldn't use function onclick placemark - console.log its 'hintname'

Tags: javascript

//on bottom i have properties of placemarks
 for (var i=0; i < placemarks.length; i++) {
             geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark([placemarks[i].latitude, placemarks[i].longitude], 
            {

```
      iconContent: placemarks[i].iconContent,
      hintContent: placemarks[i].hintContent

    }
      ,
    {preset: "islands#greenStretchyIcon"}, );


  } 
  //creating cluster of placemarks
  var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
      clusterIconContentLayout: null
  });
   clusterer.add(geoObjects);
//here is a function i wanted
```

> 

1. Blockquote

   clusterer.events.add('click', function (e) {
       // Получение координат щелчка
       var coords = e.get('position');
       alert(coords.join(', '));
   });

   map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);

   ```js
       for (var i=0; i < placemarks.length; i++) {
                geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark([placemarks[i].latitude, placemarks[i].longitude], 
               {
            
             iconContent: placemarks[i].iconContent,
             hintContent: placemarks[i].hintContent
            
           }
             ,
           {preset: "islands#greenStretchyIcon"}, );

          
         } 
         
         var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
             clusterIconContentLayout: null
         });
          clusterer.add(geoObjects);

       clusterer.events.add('click', function (e) {
           // Получение координат щелчка
           var coords = e.get('position');
           alert(coords.join(', '));
       });

         map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
   ```

   [enter link description here][1]

   [1]: https://codepen.io/Naimov/pen/oNXMXvz

Comment: please open this link

Answer (score 0):

```
ymaps.ready(init);

var placemarks = [
    {
       latitude: 41.39383842285928, 
       longitude: 69.23027402605885,
       hintContent: '22600',
       iconContent: 'post_nomi',
       balloonContent: [
              '<div>',
              '<img src="img/favicon.ico" id="img"  />',
              'samiy samiy vkusniy',
              '</div>'

      ]
    },
    {
       latitude: 41.39183842285928, 
       longitude: 69.24027402605885,
       hintContent: '25000',
       iconContent: 'post_nomi',
       balloonContent: [
              '<div>',
              '<img src="img/favicon.ico" id="img"  />',
              'samiy samiy vkusniy',
              '</div>'

      ]
    },
    {
       latitude: 41.36383842285928, 
       longitude: 69.25027402605885,
       hintContent: '97000',
       iconContent: 'post_nomi',
       domEvent: '000000',
       balloonContent: [
              '<div>',
              '<img src="img/favicon.ico" id="img"  />',
              'samiy samiy vkusniy',
              '</div>'

      ]   
    }
],

    geoObjects = [];

function init(argument) {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [41.301086, 69.243651],
        zoom: 10
        // controls: ['zoomcontrol'],
        // behaivors: ['drag']
    });

// this is a part of codes
```